# What is the series expansion of reciprocal of theta function $\frac{1}{\theta(z;q)}$?

Tags: special-functions, analytic-number-theory, theta-functions

"The" theta function is an ambiguous concept, but one definition I have found is:

$$ \theta(z;q) = (z;q)_\infty(q/z;q)_\infty = \frac{1}{(q;q)_\infty}\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}z^k q^{\binom{k}{2}} \tag{$\ast$} $$

I found this recently on [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02755) but maybe there is a textbook.  The second equation is known as the [Jacobi triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product):

$$ (q;q)_\infty(z;q)_\infty(q/z;q)_\infty = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}z^k q^{\binom{k}{2}} $$

Therefore it might make better sense to call the theta function this result of this triple product rather than definition ($\ast$) Before I forget $(z;q)$ is an abbreviation for a factorial called the [Pochammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol)

$$ (z;q) = \prod_{i=0}^\infty (1 - z q^i)$$

My question is if there is an easy expansion for the reciprocal of the theta function. I certainly could not think of one:

$$ \frac{1}{\theta(z;q)} =  \frac{1}{(z;q)_\infty} \frac{1}{(q/z;q)_\infty} = (q;q)_\infty \frac{1}{\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}z^k q^{\binom{k}{2}}} \tag{$\ast$}  = \sum \;?\,?\,?$$

Comment: There are some minus signs missing in the triple product.

Answer (score 1):

Andrews in [[1](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1984-283-02/S0002-9947-1984-0737878-3/S0002-9947-1984-0737878-3.pdf)] (equation (2.1)) sights the partial fraction expansion
$${\prod_{n\gt0}\frac{(1-q^n)^2}{(1-zq^n)(1-z^{-1}q^{n-1})}}=\sum_{m\ge0}\left(\frac{(-1)^mq^{m(m+1)/2}}{1-z^{-1}q^m}-z\frac{(-1)^mq^{m(m+1)/2}}{1-zq^m}\right)\tag{*}$$
where $1\lt|z|\lt|q|^{-1}$ and $|q|\lt1$. Making the substitution $z{\to}z/q$, one obtains an expression for $1/\theta(z,q)$. The Laurent series expansion of the righthand side of $(*)$ is given in Lemma 1 of the paper and proved in Section 2. To wit one has,
$${\prod_{n\gt0}\frac{(1-q^n)^2}{(1-zq^n)(1-z^{-1}q^{n-1})}}=\sum_{\substack{(N,r)\in\mathbb{Z}\\r\ge|N|}}
{(-1)^{r+N}z^Nq^{(r^2-N^2)/2+(r+N)/2}}\tag{**}$$.
**References**
[[1](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1984-283-02/S0002-9947-1984-0737878-3/S0002-9947-1984-0737878-3.pdf)] [HECKE
MODULAR
FORMS
AND
THE KAC-PETERSON
IDENTITIES, G.E.Andrews](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1984-283-02/S0002-9947-1984-0737878-3/S0002-9947-1984-0737878-3.pdf)